# Data cleansing - how to decide which names are misspellings or are equivalent but slightly different?

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-analysis, data-cleaning

We have table with companies names and a numeric primary key identity. We are cleaning up the data and we have discovered the name column is full of similar names that represent the same company.

E.g. BA and Ba or GTC Ltd and GTC Limited.

Is there anyway using SQL server that we can get counts and summary of all items that have similar names and list of IDs. I wondered if there was some sort of similarity comparison we could set a threshold value for etc

We need to present a list of names to the client that look like they need merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is "No".  Name rectification is a hard problem.  Two names like "GTC Ltd" and "GTC Limited" are more different than "GTC" and "GTE" (by more obvious measures).  There are outside service bureaus and special-purpose software for this purpose.

If you are dealing with a smallish amount of data, I would suggest that you alphabetize the values, load them into Excel, and add a column in Excel with the "official" name.  You can then re-import this as a table in the database to do what you want.  It might help if you remove known suffixes and prefixes, such as "ltd", "bros", "partners" and so on.

If you do try to go down the path of something like `soundex()`, then be sure that you [understand it well](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx).  For instance, the `soundex()` values of the following two strings are the same:  "gte, blah blah blah" and "gdteey, junk goes here".

Comment: Thanks for that. Yeah I may look at something like Google refine rather than SQL Server which doesn't really have any inbuilt support for the issue

Answer (score 1):

Your answer lies in the [`SoundEx()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) and [`Difference()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) functions.

```
DECLARE @a varchar(50) = 'BA'
      , @b varchar(50) = 'Ba'
;

SELECT @a
     , @b
     , SoundEx(@a)
     , SoundEx(@b)
     , Difference(@a, @b)
;

SET @a = 'GTC Ltd';
SET @b = 'GTC Limited';

SELECT @a
     , @b
     , SoundEx(@a)
     , SoundEx(@b)
     , Difference(@a, @b)
;

SET @a = 'BLAH';

SELECT @a
     , @b
     , SoundEx(@a)
     , SoundEx(@b)
     , Difference(@a, @b)
;
```

This of `SoundEx` as *"sounds like"* - it's a function that returns a representation of the input which you can compare with other outputs.

The `Difference()` function returns a value between 0 and 4, where the higher numbers represent better matches.

Comment: Any idea how I would apply that to the table as a whole to produce a summary list of similar names?

Comment: Looks technically great- however practically it produces 3338 rows with 4 for difference. There are only 1686 companies so not sure SQL server functions are going to be up to it

Comment: Combined with LEVENSHTEIN as well this is looking more promising

Comment: @GraemeMiller the query performs a `CROSS` join which produces a Cartesian product. This is so we can compare every row with every other. We then filter it down based on the unique key so that we only compare each combination once (i.e. only one of `a=b` and `b=a`) and exclude self-comparisons as the `<` doesn't include an equals operator (i.e. no `a=a`). Finally, we retrieve only those with a high (4 is the highest value returned) similarity. I can't see your data but if you follow these rules your result should be *correct*.

Comment: @GraemeMiller You could also add to the `WHERE` clause: `x1.val <> x2.val` to exclude exact matches.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plenty of functions to check similarities. MS SQL provides [`SOUNDEX`](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187384.aspx) and [`DIFFERENCE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) functions, which I've never actually used.

Although I once used [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (minimum edits to covert string1 into string2) in PHP and it was very effictient. Here is  the [Devio's implementation in TSQL](http://devio.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/calculating-levenshtein-distance-in-tsql/) as a function which you can put into your code:

```
SELECT 
    LEVENSHTEIN(COL1, COL2) 
FROM 
    ExampleTable
```

Or in `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT 
    COL1, COL2
FROM
    ExampleTable
WHERE
    LEVENSHTEIN(COL1, COL2) < 5
```

Here I'd suggest you to implement some `CASE - WHEN - THEN` logic, to find the correct levenshtein distance for you needs.

Comment: Any idea how I would apply that to the table as a whole to produce a summary list of similar names? I just have a single table so I need to compare all the names and produce a list of similar names I guess. Guess a cross join and compare all of them to each other

Comment: Combined this with gvee answer but it doesn't really give great results. Maybe if I removed all of Ltd/limited etc it would get closer. Possibly also lots of them are just initials which it thinks are really similar but aren't

Comment: @GraemeMiller - you can combine it with a dictionary table to have an abbreviation and full name

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI` and `LIKE` operator to check for  `BA and Ba` .
But for `GTC Ltd and GTC Limited` you can still use the same but then you should manually check them and merge carefully.